# Comparison of different way of implementing the elbow method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am confused as I see different ways to implement the elbow method to identify the correct number of clusters in Kmean and they produce slightly different results.

One method is described here [Sklearn kmeans equivalent of elbow method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540751/sklearn-kmeans-equivalent-of-elbow-method)
and is using `kmeans_inertia_` the other methos is described here https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-elbow-method/
and is using the following command.

`distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0])`
 I am wondering what does Kmeans_inertia_ does ? and are both implementation correct ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "correct" for something that is not at all well-defined.

The elbow method is an extremely crude heuristic for which I am not aware of any formal definition, nor a reference.

Both methods will supposedly most often yield the same k...

But by the concept of k-means, the "correct" way to use it is with squared errors, *not* with Euclidean distance. Because k-means minimizes squared errors, it does not minimize Euclidean distances (try to prove this! You can't because there are counterexamples).

Answer (score 2):

Both the [scikit-Learn User Guide on KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) and [Andrew Ng's CS229 Lecture notes on k-means](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes7a.pdf) indicate that the elbow method minimizes the **sum** of squared **distances** between cluster points and their cluster centroids.  The sklearn documentation calls this "inertia" and points out that it is subject to the drawback of inflated **Euclidean distances** in high-dimensional spaces.  Ng calls this minimization of the "distortion function".  One can, however, find [examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elbow-method-for-optimal-value-of-k-in-kmeans/) of the definition of distortion being "the **average** of the squared distances from the cluster centers of the respective clusters" (emphasis mine) in contrast to "inertia" being the **sum** of the squared distances.  While confusing, and  confirming these terms are not consistently defined, it suggests to me both work.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) you can see that both distortion and inertia both are the sum of distance for each point to its center.

Answer (score 0):

I find many examples around that use this formula, claiming that they calculate the distortion. However in my understanding is seems wrong:

```py
distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)) / X.shape[0])
```

If you want to calculate the sum of squared distances, it should be:

```py
distortions.append(sum(np.min(cdist(X, kmeanModel.cluster_centers_, 'euclidean'), axis=1)**2) / X.shape[0])
```