# Evaluate clustering performance

Tags: python, cluster-computing, evaluation

1. My raw data looks like:

   ```
   df =

           long lat long lat long lat long lat 

       1   11   6   15   19  23   27  30   34
       2   12   7   16   20  24   28  31   35
       3   13   8   17   21  25   29  32   36
       ...
       96  14   9   18   22  26   30  33   37
   ```

   Where: column of `1,2,3,..,96` are  "`taxi_id`". It means we have `96` cars.

   Other columns are representing location of a car, by assuming them as a couple.

   Example: taxi car with a label `1` has location `(11,6)(15,19)(23,27)(30,34)`
2. So, I need to cluster them to see the most common trajectories used
   by these taxi drivers.

   To do that I have calculated the "some" distance matrix, then calculated its similarity matrix and applied final matrix to [Affinity Propagation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html)
3. Affinity Propagation code:

   ```
   from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation

   af = AffinityPropagation(preference=-6).fit(X)
   cluster_centers_indices = af.cluster_centers_indices_
   labels = af.labels_ 

   # Some code to calculate number of clusters (3 in this case)
   # Some code to check which "taxi_id" related to clusters
   ```
4. And final data looks like:

   ```
   final_df = 

                  long    lat
           1      11      22
       0   2      33      44
           3      55      66
           ...    ...     ...
           45     12      13
       2   46     14      15
           47     16      17
   ```

I want to evaluate my clustering. And I do not know how. I did not predict anything, so how can I use the `sklearn` evaluations metrics? I can not even find a logic (what exactly to evaluate)? Maybe Distance between two clusters (CD)? Do you have any ideas or solution code how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can not even find a logic (what exactly to evaluate)? Maybe Distance between two clusters (CD)?

You are on the right way, one approach is to measure the distance between all cluster points in a cluster. The idea is to test it for a different number of clusters, in your case oyu are only have 3 clusters (0-2).

The silhouette score for example is one of this techniques.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silhouette_(clustering)

> Do you have any ideas or solution code how to proceed?

Here a a lot of solutions on stackoverflow:
[How to use silhouette score in k-means clustering from sklearn library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138686/how-to-use-silhouette-score-in-k-means-clustering-from-sklearn-library)

Another one could be the elbow method for you:
[Sklearn kmeans equivalent of elbow method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540751/sklearn-kmeans-equivalent-of-elbow-method)

The question of all this methods they try to answer: how many clusters should I pick? If you know the number of clusters you want to have upfront, this can help you to judge about the risk and qualities of the clusters.

Comment: Thanks for idea. Actually I was planning to apply `RandomizedSearchCV` by `sklearn`. But I found that it is for supervised learning.

What is concerning the cluster number, having found evaluation method, then I will create a loop to change the values of main parameter, which affect my number of cluster (preference and damping in case of Affinity Propagation), and I will apply evaluation in the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `clusteval` library can be of use. This library contains five methods that can be used to evaluate clusterings; *silhouette*, *dbindex*, *derivative*, *dbscan *and *hdbscan*.

```
pip install clusteval
```

I would suggest dbscan for your case:

```
# Import library
from clusteval import clusteval

# Set parameters
ce = clusteval(method='dbscan')

# Fit to find optimal number of clusters using dbscan
out = ce.fit(df.values)

# Make plot of the cluster evaluation
ce.plot()

# Make scatter plot. Note that the first two coordinates are used for plotting.
ce.scatter(df.values)
```